# How to match words in different languages by JavaScript regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a strings in different languages. I need to get only characters without numbers, '-', '/', ')', ... But seams JavaScript regexp '\w' matches only English.

http://jsfiddle.net/d9BRC/

Comment: check http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research, it seems `\w` does not handle unicode characters, you can do this with `\p{L}` (Letters), but again javascript does not support this.

Here is a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/d9BRC/1/), taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode/8933546#8933546)